# Como é feito o loop de fim de arquivo

Tags: c, arquivo, while

Tipo, eu sei que a função feof() retorna 0 se não encontrou um final de arquivo e que ela exige 1 parâmetro, que é o ponteiro_pra_variável_tipo_FILE, até aí tudo bem.

Se eu faço o while assim ele funciona que nem o outro de baixo mas eu não entendo como.

```
while(!feof(ponteiro_pra_variavel_tipo_FILE)) {
}
```

O correto não seria testar assim ?

```
while(feof(ponteiro_pra_variavel_tipo_FILE) == 0){
}
```

Como é que ele sabe através de `!feof(ponteiro_pra_variavel_tipo_FILE)`, que a função está retornando `0` ?

Comment: Leitura útil relacionada (em inglês): [Why is “while ( !feof (file) )” always wrong?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O que acontece é que como C não possui o tipo booleano, ele interpreta as variáveis inteiras para avaliar uma expressão, sendo que zero está para false e diferente de zero está para true, assim como estamos acostumados a usar.
Portanto não há a necessidade da utilização de `feof(ponteiro_pra_variavel_tipo_FILE) == 0)` pois a própria expressão já retorna um valor inteiro que é o suficiente para a avaliação do `while`.

Para maior esclarecimento nesse seu caso, a função `feof` retorna 0 quando ainda há arquivo a ser processado, logo ambas as expressões citadas por você como exemplo tem o mesmo sigfinicado. O `while` se repetirá enquanto a expressão for verdadeira(não tiver acabado o arquivo).

Comment: Então enquanto a função feof estiver retornando false(0) o meu while() continua a se repetir. E quando ela retornar true ele termina. Isso Murilo ?

Comment: Sim @GuilhermedeOliveira, é por isso que se usa a negação(!) no caso que você colocou de primeiro exemplo. A função `feof` retorna 0 quando ainda há arquivo a ser processado. Se a resposta serviu, marque a questão como respondida.

Comment: Melhor explicando, há de se ter cuidado ao analisar a expressão pois o resultado do `feof` ser 0 não quer dizer que o while se repetirá enquanto for falso. Por isso foi isso que se usa a negação(!) no seu primeiro exemplo e a comparação(==) no segundo exemplo.

Comment: A resposta serviu sim Murilo ! Muito obrigado cara !

Answer (score 2):

A função feof diz se alguma função de leitura do arquivo já tentou ler alguma entrada e não conseguiu devido ao fim do arquivo. Ela não diz se uma função de leitura vai conseguir ler a próxima entrada.

O que você deve fazer é ler o valor de retorno das suas funções de leitura e ver se a leitura falhou devido ao fim do arquivo. Por exemplo, as funções `getchar` e `scanf` retornam `EOF` quando não há caracteres a serem lidos. Algums exemplos disso em uso:

```
int c;
while(c = getchar(), c != EOF){
    ...
}

int nr;
int blah;
while(EOF != scanf("%d", &blah)){
    ...
}
```

---

Voltando a sua pergunta, tem a ver com o fato de "verdadeiro ou falso" ser representado com inteiros em C. Tente fazer uns printfs pra ter uma idéia:

```
printf("%d\n", (5 == 5));
printf("%d\n", (5 == 6));
printf("%d\n", !(5 == 6));
printf("%d\n", !3);
```

E resultado disso é que em C `!x` e `x != 0` são equivalentes.

Answer (score 0):

Como o colega acima colocou: o C interpreta diretamente, já que, por padrão, ele tem esse "== 0" automático,

Creio que em linhas bem gerais pode ser comparado ao caso do

```
for (x=0;x<MAX;x++)
   o que executar
```

ao invés de

```
x=o;
while (x<MAX){
execução do código;
x=x+1;
}
```

Tudo pra poupar umas linhas e o código ficar mais enxuto e de fácil assimilação.
Pelo menos eu vejo dessa forma.

Abraço